# Equals two Variables from two Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create simple cash register.

I already have two `ArrayLists`, one is my "DataBase" second is used to store purchased products. How can I equal ID from DataBase with ID from input product? In the `ArrayList`s I have variable id, name and price.

```
Arraylists<Products> products = new ArrayLists<Products>(); <- Database
ArrayLists<purchased> purchased = new ArrayLists<purchased>() <-List of purchased products
```

I passed to the function object Product.

Comment: Can you try to explain your question better?  I don't quite understand.

Comment: i Try. Im writting cash register. I have steps:
1. One input devices: bar codes scanner
-two output devices: LCD display and printer
2. Single product sale: products bar code is scanned and:
-if the product is found in products database then it's name and price is printed on LCD display
-if the product is not found then error message printed on LCD
-if the code scanned is empty then error message "Invalid bar-code" is printed on LCD display. So i created class Products, next i create Arraylist of this products and i create function scan(Product p). Now i don't know how to equals products

Answer (score 0):

For such case it is better to use Maps rather than Lists. IDs will be keys and objects will be values.

With Lists you have to loop through them and compare ID,,  each time you need to find a match. But with Maps you just use dbmap.get(ID) or productMap.get(ID) and you have your object instantly.

Comment: I have another one question. Already Its my code:https://pastebin.com/YjEy6MRd
I have 4x products.add(...) and i don't want have all this products in 
produkty.put(0,products). I want to have one product in one put like produkty.put(0, products[0]) , produkty.put(1, products[1]) ... and so for. How can i do this?

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean all products under one key, but each individual product by it's ID. i.e `productMap.put(product[i].getId(),product[i])`... Sorry I type from phone...